# How do I calculate the product of the occurrence of elements in 2 lists?

Tags: scala, list, function, methods

I have created a function that calculates the number of occurrences of element in a list, whereby if I pass the string

```
"d b d b d"
```

into the function, then it will return

```
(b -> 2, d -> 3)
```

Now what I want to do, is to create a new function that takes two arguments both List[String]

```
def foo(a: List[String], b: List[String]) : Int = {

}
```

And lets say I pass

```
List("a", "b", "b", "c", "d") 
occurrences of this list = (a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 1, d -> 1)

List("d", "b", "d", "b", "d")
occurrences of this list = (b -> 2, d -> 3)
```

into this function, it will calculate the occurrences of each element in each list, and then it calculates the product of each occurrence between the list. Therefore the expected answer from passing these two lists would be 7:

```
1*0 + 2*2 + 1*0 + 1*3 = 7
 a     b     c     d
```

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this:

```
  def count(string: String): Map[String, Int] =
    string.split(" ").groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.length)

  def multiply(m1: Map[String, Int], m2: Map[String, Int]): Map[String, Int] = {
    val allKeys = m1.keySet.union(m2.keySet)
    allKeys.map(key => key -> m1.getOrElse(key, 0) * m2.getOrElse(key, 0)).toMap
  }

  val freq1 = count("a b b c d")
  val freq2 = count("d b d b d")

  val multiplied = multiply(freq1, freq2)
  val sum = multiplied.values.sum
```